# How to apply association rules for test transactions in R?

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I have two datasets including training and test. For training dataset, I extracted many association rules as below. Now I would like to use these rules for test transaction dataset. I need to find transaction ids which match these rules.
Help me!

```
library("arules");

candidates<-read.transactions(file="D:\\Ranker\\Candidates.csv",rm.duplicates=TRUE, format="single",sep=",",col=c(1,2));
candidates.test<-read.transactions(file="D:\\Ranker\\Candidates_test.csv",rm.duplicates=TRUE, format="single",sep=",",col=c(1,2));

rules <- apriori(candidates, parameter = list(supp=0.0000001, conf=1, target="rules"),appearance = list(rhs=c("no"),default="lhs"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am completely off mark, but I think that the generated model already contains the information you are looking for.

You can `inspect(candidates[1 : 20])` and take note of the confidence and lift as well as `inspect(sort(candidates, by = "lift") [1 : 20])`